# Как вернуть старый вид страниц wordpress 5.0.3?

Tags: wordpress

Делал месяц назад сайт. Сайт был на 4.8. Обновился до 5.0.2 При обновление меня спросили если я хочу вернуть старый вид страниц, и я вернул ибо мне нужен старый вид. 
Теперь я сделал новый сайт, и сразу установил 5.0.3 WP . Как тут вернуть старый вид страниц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не очень понятен, я так понимаю Вам нужен старый редактор страниц в панели администратора при редактировании записи? Наиболее простой способ установить плагин Disable Gutenberg (https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/) или вручную добавив фильтры:

```
if( 'disable_gutenberg' ){
    add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 100 );

    add_action( 'admin_init', function(){
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', [ 'WP_Privacy_Policy_Content', 'notice' ] );
        add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', [ 'WP_Privacy_Policy_Content', 'notice' ] );
    } );
}
```

Если нужно оставить возможность использовать Гутенберг на сайте (иметь возможность одни статьи править в новом редакторе, а другие в классическом), то жесткое отключение Гутенберга - не вариант. В этом случае разработчики WordPress рекомендуют установить плагин Classic Editor(https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/).

После установки и активации плагина, нужно зайти на страницу настроек: Настройки > Написание и выбрать какой редактор будет использоваться по умолчанию, а также дать/запретить возможность выбора редактора пользователям.